# How can I see how much bandwidth my website uses?

Tags: web, firefox-addon, bandwidth

I'm looking for a Firefox addon which will track how much bandwidth a page is using. This could be a regular HTML page or GMail with the chat feature using Javascript. Is there anything that will help me optimize my page like this?

Comment: How is this programming related?

Comment: gnovice, I don't think it's any further from programming than asking what IDE to use. They're all tools for programming efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FireBug has function that allows you to see how much bandwidth and how long certain scripts, pages, images, etc take to load

Comment: The suggested solution, YSlow, is a plugin for FireBug.

Comment: I was referring to the FireBug Net Panel, which is NOT YSlow

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) is what you're looking for?

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted as it can't really handle AJAX requests but I guess maybe there aren't any other options.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Install Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)
2. [Download YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5369)
3. [Review the YSlow User Guide](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/help/index.html)